# How to set Photoshop CC window size to 1280x720 via AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I'm trying to resize the Photosshop CC window to 1280x720 to record it in 720p. I tried multiple ways, including AppleScript, SizeUP! app, terminal etc but none work.

Here's an example of AppleScript I'm using:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Adobe Photoshop CC" 
    display dialog (get name of window 1) 
    set position of window 1 to {50, 50}   
    set size of window 1 to {1280, 720} 
end tell
```

It does set the position, but does not set the size of the application window.

When I try

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "Adobe Photoshop CC"
           tell window 1
            set {size, position} to {{1280, 720}, {150, 150}}
            end tell end tell
```

I get the error `"System Events got an error: Can’t set application process \"Adobe Photoshop CC\" to {1280, 720}." number -10006 from application process "Adobe Photoshop CC"`

I have also tried to set bounds instead of size with the following code to no avail.

```
set the_application to "/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC/Adobe Photoshop CC.app"
tell application the_application
    activate
    set bounds of window 1 to {1, 1, 1281, 721}
end tell
```

and I get `"Adobe Photoshop CC got an error: Can’t set window 1 to {1, 1, 1281, 721}." number -10006 from window 1`

SizeUP! app does change the position but does not effect the Photoshop window size.

Does anyone know how can I resize the Photoshop application window on a Mac to 1280x720 to record it in 720p?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a window containing an image of that size, or of a size within a range of sizes, or any size? There are a few options, I think, if the actual image size is 1280x720, but other than that, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm talking about the application window itself, not the image size you can open and re-size *inside* the application. Any thoughts are ideas?

Comment: Hi @Firefly. You didn't answer my question, but perhaps I should've been clearer. I was asking you if the size of the image (not the window) is always different, or is there a set of sizes, or one size, or if it is unknown.

Comment: @CRGreen it isn't about an image. There could be an image of known size, unknown size, multiple sizes, or no images. The question is about scripted control of the Photoshop window by external applications.

Comment: @Barney, I know what the question was about. I was asking to see if there was a particular set of limitations or situations that would make what he was trying to do possible with some sort of hack. So, like I said, he's out of luck I'm afraid.

Comment: @CRGreen ah OK. Do you think it could be (hackily) done if you had a document of the desired size / pixel ratio to frame the UI around?

Comment: I was thinking that if he was always actually working with a 720p image (or images of that ratio), that it may be possible to work with some of the menu commands that sort of 'reset' the position to the same place (Screen modes, Actual pixels, for example). It seemed to me that if someone wanted to _always_ record in a 720p window, why would they be dealing with other aspect ratios with wasted space. Anyway, it seems this is another question that sort of faded away.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using the latest version of macOS High Sierra and Adobe Photoshop CC 2017

```
set thePosition to {0, 20}
set theSize to {1280, 720}
set theBoundz to {thePosition} & {theSize}

tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2017" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell window 1 of ¬
    (process 1 whose it is frontmost) to set {position, size} to theBoundz
```